# How to make a currency amount field with blank value instead of 0.00

Tags: abap

I want to put currency amount field blank instead of 0.00.

Comment: can you provide an example and more context please. May you just have to change a placeholder or alternative value.

Comment: Please edit your question to add context, it's currently way too broad (this kind of question is difficult to generalize). See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Currently people might give so many different answers (that could be for UI5, BSP, WebDynpro, Dynpro, HTML, ALV classic, Adobe form, IDoc and so on). Same issue for future visitors, they might look for some technologies and don't find it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- **ALV**: `NO_ZERO = abap_true` in fieldcatalog structure `LVC_S_FCAT`
- **SALV**: call method `SET_ZERO` of class `CL_SALV_COLUMN` *(you need to get the columns reference, google [code examples](https://answers.sap.com/questions/6548139/hide-zeros-in-a-column-using-clsalvtable.html))*
- **Sapscript/Smartforms**: use flag `I` (suppress initial value output) as in `&ZAMOUNT(I)&`
- **WRITE** statement: Add `NO-ZERO` before the `.`
- **String templates**: `lv_string = |{ lv_amnt ZERO = NO }|.`